# $\nabla f=0$ on an open set $U \subset C$ implies $f$ locally constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose for some open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ that $\partial_xf=\partial_yf=0$ for every $u \in U$. Show that $f$ is locally constant. I'm explicity told I can use the fact that if $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $h'(x)=0$ for $x \in [a,b]$ then $h$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

I for sure don't want a solution. I don't see the tension in this problem? What's stopping me from fixing two points $p_1=(x,y),p_2=(x',y') \in U$ and just applying the MVT in one dimension on both coordinates?

This is clearly wrong since it implies the stronger result that $f$ constant on $U$.

Can someone give an example where $\nabla f=0$ on a set but it is not constant?

Comment: locally constant implies constant on connected components, so the only examples as required are when $U$ is disconnected and $f$ has different constant values on its components

Comment: So if $U$ is disconnected I just do the same proof for all it's components?

Comment: Or even easier; I just fix some open rectangle around $p$

Comment: Yes, that second plan is perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that $U$ may not be connected, so there will not neccesarily be a path from $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$ inside $U$ (much less a path made of two straight lines!)

For a simple example, let $U = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert < 1\} \cup \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert 4 - z \rvert < 1\}$. This is a disjoint union of two open disks, and we can define a smooth function $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ which sends one disk to $0$ and the other to $1$.

Instead, you should write a proof which directly shows that the definition of "locally constant" is satisfied: take a point $x \in U$, and produce an open neighborhood $x \in U_0 \subseteq U$ such that $f|_{U_0}$ is constant. If you pick $U_0$ correctly, you can use your path-connectedness argument!